# Subquery for PIvot table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a query to generate a Pivot. The code is running absolutely fine.
Instead of hard coding the value("1","2","3"), IS it possible to write a subquery?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT * from #Registered2
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(s.Registered_customer_Count)
    FOR [Offer_cover_id] IN ("1","2","3")
)AS pvt
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[Offer_cover_id]) 
            FROM #Registered2 c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT  ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select*
                from Registered2 
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 SUM(Registered_customer_Count)
                for [Offer_cover_id] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

Comment: This is working perfect but the output is repeating the columns 1,2,3 twice.